# How to update User data in domain classes of grails with shiro framework

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, shiro

I am using grails 2.5.5 , hibernate4 - 4.3.10 & shiro - 1.2.1.

Domain class looks like this :

```
class Test{
String name
User createdBy
static constraints = {
}
def beforeValidate() {
    def subject

    try {
        subject = SecurityUtils.subject
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error "Error obtaining the subject.  Message is [${e.message}]"
    }
    log.error "createdBy :: [${createdBy}]"
    createdBy = (subject ? User.get( subject.principal ) :
            User.findByUsername("ashutosh"))
    log.error "createdBy :: [${createdBy}]"
    }
}
```

User class is :

```
class User {
String username
String passwordHash

static hasMany = [ roles: Role, permissions: String ]

static constraints = {
    username(nullable: false, blank: false, unique: true)
}
```

}

I want to insert current logged in user as createdBy in test domain classes.

While running this code I am getting below error :

```
Error obtaining the subject.  Message is [No such property: SecurityUtils for class: Test]
```

Please suggest how can I insert the current user data in Test while inserting it to database.

Comment: verify that you have proper import for SecurityUtils `import org.apache.shiro.SecurityUtils`

Comment: Thanks Sandeep. I rechecked. It was not there.